# Marklogic Secuirty Roles

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I want to give user a new role by which user will be able to get access to fetch all the users from the **Security** database but we cannot give that user a role named as **"Security"** because this role give access to the full security database to that particular user . We only want the user will get permission to fetch list of users only.

Answer (score 2):

[Temporarily Increasing Privileges with Amps](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/execute#id_54880)

> Amps provide users with additional authorization to execute a specific function. Assigning the user this authorization permanently could compromise the security of the system. When executing an amped function, the user is part of an amped role, which temporarily grants the user additional privileges and permissions of that role. Amps enable you to limit the effect of the additional roles (privileges and permissions) to a specific function.

High-level steps:

1. Create a new  role that represents the functionality required
2. Create your own function that runs the query you need.
3. Make sure that the function has a security-assert to limit access to the function.
4. AMP that function with the elevated roles required.
5. Assign the new role to you user.

‐‐---

Basically: when using your wrapper function, the extra role is [amped](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/execute#id_54880) on to the calling role- but the function can only be used by the intended group.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Mads. It reminds me to take more time and write complete answers. I was waiting iutside for someone and answered quickly. Will endeavour to write nore complete responses in the future.

Comment: As a side note when dancing around the security items represented by sec:some-function(), always check to see if the same functionality is also already available in the XDMP namespace. Some of the less critical read-only functions are already conveniently wrapped and available without the need for executing the SEC namespaced version.  This does not include the topic of this post(listing users) but xan be helpful.    When I think I need a sec:xx item, i first look for the same or compatible functionality under the xdmp namespace.